# Switching authentication between passport-jwt and passport-google-oauth20

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, passport.js

My frontend is in React and backend is Node/Express. I am using 2 types of Passport strategies:

- JWT
- Google

Some users log in with email/password and are authenticated by `passport.Authenticate('jwt', {session:false})` while some users are `authenticated by passport.Authenticate('google')`. Both type of uses get authenticated successfully (independently).

The issue is the JWT users send a bearer token and Google users are automatic through session cookies.

So, if I create a route like:

```
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), showProfile)
```

this will authenticate only the JWT users and fail the Google users.
If I change it to:

```
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('google'), showProfile)
```

this will authenticate only the Google users.

I want a generic code to authenticate both types of users. So if I create a middleware like:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    // bearer token exists
    //execute passport authentication for jwt
  }else{
    //check if req.user exists
    //if yes call next()
 }
```

Is there a way to switch between the two middleware calls? How to make both JWT and Google validations. I have no issues with Google login and stuff, just the  application's protected routes.

Comment: My application was a fully working application with passport-jwt, wherein my application has hooks created for accessing axios. it creates the authHeaders which includes const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); if (token) { return { Authorization: Bearer ${token} }; }

Comment: My issue started when I had to extend the application to allow google authentication. By default my backend considers that my users are sending jwt tokens, however, due to the fact that google auth uses cookies and it updates the req object with the user, I will have to specifically check the req.user value to authenticate it. So, the same single route needs 2 different authentications. that is the issue. HOW CAN I LOOK AT THE REQ AND SWITCH TO THE CORRECT PASSPORT STRATEGY?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally.

```js
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.headers)
  const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']
  console.log({bearerHeader})
  if (bearerHeader){
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ')
    req.token = bearer[1]
    next()
  }else{
    next()
  }
}

const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next)=> {
  if (req.user){
    console.log('OAuth User was found')
    next()
  }else {
    if (req.token) {
      console.log('Bearer token was found')
      // user is a jwt user
      passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false})(req, res, next)
      // next()
    }else{
      res.sendStatus(401)
    }
  }
}
userController.get('/userList', verifyToken, isLoggedIn,(req, res) => {
  User.find({}, (err, result) => res.status(200).json({data: result}))
}
)
```

Yes, there is a lot of scope of refinement, which I will do in due course.

Answer (score 0):

I though you re asking about only one custom middleware, how about test to make into one ? if it doesn't work unfortunately i will remove my answer.

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {   // or req.isAuthenticated() ?
        console.log('OAuth User was found')
        next();
    } else if (req.headers.authorization) {
        passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false})
        (req, res, next);
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({error: "ACCESS DENIED"})
    }
};

userController.get('/userList', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, (err, result) => res.status(200).json({data: result}))
});
```

Comment: Thanks! basically, we do app.use(passport) in the server, so the passport middleware saves the token in the req.token... it checks all various places where the token can be placed and finally saves in req.token. It is best to check req.token. checking in req.headers would be like hardcoding... I think! :(

Comment: Ok i see, I am still new in jwtToken, then if the passport middleware save the token in the req.token after checking various place why don't you check directly the req.token, why do you need to check the header first and assign it to the req.token ?

Comment: Passport saves the user object in req.user, I am saving the token in req.token. isLoggedIn method is called in all protected routes. it first checks if the user object exists in the req.user, else it checks req.token . There may be several ways to do the same thing, but this technique worked for me and it has a proper pattern to follow.